# How to use Firebase Cloud Messaging with an existing service worker in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have setup Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to use an existing service worker.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => registerServiceWorker('sw'))
  .then(registration => {
    console.log('[App] Successful service worker registration', registration);
    messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
    // ...
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('[App] Service worker registration failed', err));
```

The message listener is registered in the constructor of the AppComponent through a service.

```
@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  private messaging = firebase.messaging();
  public hidden: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  public subscribe() {
    this.messaging.onMessage((payload: any) => {
      console.log(payload);
      this.hidden = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I properly receive and log all messages. However the hidden property is not set to false.

**Is there some kind of digest mechanism to add in order to apply changes in an Angular (4) app on FCM message received?**

**EDIT 1:**
The property gets updated as soon as I click on a button or any widget on the page

**EDIT 2:**
I managed to implement a workaround by triggering a change detection using the tick method of ApplicationRef. Doesn't seem ideal though.